# widgets for ChoiceField in modelform

Tags: python, django

I'm using a modelform for my form `Post` and I'm using a bootstrap starter code as my `base.html` but because I use the    `{% csrf_token %} {{form.as_p}}` on my `add_blog` page, bootstrap doesn't work and because of that it needs `class='form-control'`, I have managed to do that on all of my fields but Choice input, if I do include my author(choicefield) in the widgets I get a TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:

    model = Post
    fields = ("title", "title_tag", "author", "body")
    widget = forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"})

    widgets = {
        'title': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'title_tag': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'body': Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'author': ChoiceField(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A [**`ChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) is a *form field*, not a *form widget*. The default widget of a `ChoiceField` is a [**`Select`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Select). You thus can specify to use this widget with:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'title_tag', 'author', 'body')

        widgets = {
            'title': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'title_tag': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'body': Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'author': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

Comment: thanks so much it worked and I didn't know the diffrence between a form field and a form widget I knew it but didn't realize the diffrence, I appreciate it,